# Creating a user with only one role using JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following `RoleRepository`:

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long>{
}
```

When creating a new user the following is executed in `UserServiceImpl`:

```
@Override
public void save(User user) {
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll()));
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

My database has two roles, USER and ADMIN. This means that when a user iscreated it has both roles. I'd like to change this so only the USER role is created and ADMIN can be assigned at a later point in time.

I thought I could add `List<String> findByName(String name);` to `RoleRepository` and update `user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll()));` to `user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findByName("USER")));` in `UserServiceImpl` but this didn't work. How is this done?

Comment: Hint: Compare the return types of your `findByName` and `findAll`.

Comment: Thanks @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-. One of those ones I'd have looked at all night and not spotted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RoleRepository should be:

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long>{
    List<Role> findAllByName(String name);
}
```

And and update `user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll()));` to `user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAllByName("USER")));` in `UserServiceImpl`.